# Doctrine2 WHERE on optional JOIN

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, where-clause

This fails

```
$builder = $repo->createQueryBuilder("ub")
    ->where("ub.badge = :badge AND ub.user = :user AND ub.project = :project")
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->setParameter("project", $project)
    ->setParameter("user", $user)
    ->setParameter("badge", $badge);
```

The `project` may or may not be present and results in this error

> Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier

If the query is changed to the following it still fails, suggesting its the project rather than any other entity. This still fails even if there are no rows in the `ub` (UserBadge) table.

```
$builder = $userBadgesRepo->createQueryBuilder("ub")
    ->where("ub.project = :project")
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->setParameter("project", $project);
```

How can I change this query to work with a `project` in the WHERE statement?

The UserBadge YML

```
Acme\NameBundle\Entity\UserBadges:
    type: entity
    table: user_badges
    repositoryClass: Acme\NameBundle\Entity\UserBadgesRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

        added:
            type: datetime

    manyToOne:
        badge:
            targetEntity: Acme\NameBundle\Entity\Badge
            inversedBy: badge_users
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: CASCADE
                name: badge_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        user:
            targetEntity: Acme\NameBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: user_badges
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: CASCADE
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        project:
            targetEntity: Acme\NameBundle\Entity\Project
            inversedBy: project_badges
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: CASCADE
                name: project_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: true
```

Project YML

```
Acme\NameBundle\Entity\Project:
    type: entity
    table: project
    repositoryClass: Acme\NameBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
**SNIP**

    oneToMany:
         project_badges:
             targetEntity: Acme\NameBundle\Entity\UserBadges
             mappedBy: project
```

Comment: Does the project entity have an identifier? (e.g. a member tagged with @id annotation)

Comment: I believe so, see edit which no contains the YML

Comment: What about the Project entity though - does *that* have an id defined?

Comment: See new edit, yes it has an ID and reference to the UserBadges entity

Comment: You've omitted the useful bit - so `Acme\NameBundle\Entity\UserBadges.fields.id.id = true`

Comment: Ah there it is. Well that looks OK :(

Comment: I don't understand. `UserBadges` has an `id` and `Project` has an `id`. UB references the Project id.

Comment: I take it that user and badge also have ids defined?

Comment: Yeah they all have AUTO ids. Each as an Entity works just fine. Its just that query that fails.

Comment: Well, I'd trace where in Doctrine that error is being throw, and work backwards from there. It *looks* like Doctrine can't find an id column for one of those entities, but if you have a member tagged with id=true in each entities, it must be something else...

Comment: Its definitely the project entity, if I remove the other where statements and just leave project then it still fails.

Comment: Its an Entity instance. As is User and Badge. UserBadges is essentially a joining table, but I needed additional columns hence why its its own Entity and not just a simple joining table.

Comment: A UB always has a User and a Badge, sometimes to has a Project too. If there is no Project then this query will not return any without a Project. It will only return those UserBadges for a specific User, with a specific Badge  on a specific Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$builder = $repo->createQueryBuilder("ub")
    ->leftJoin('ub.project', 'p')
    ->join('ub.badge', 'b')
    ->join('ub.user', 'u')
    ->where("b.id = :badge AND u.id = :user AND p.id = :project")
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->setParameter("project", $project->getId())
    ->setParameter("user", $user->getId())
    ->setParameter("badge", $badge->getId());
```

**Explanation** (extracted from comment):

The relationships are stored by reference (id) and you can directly query by those, but not the object itself because at the time of the query sql doesn't know about the table of the other entity. You can only compare relationship objects after you manually joined them.

Please also read section 5 here: http://labs.octivi.com/mastering-symfony2-performance-doctrine

Comment: This errors; `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 141 near 'p) = :projec': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.`

Comment: That has worked! But why? Can you explain why my code did not work originally?

Comment: Oh wait, no not seen that, its working with the initial version. Should I amend to this version?

Comment: I just don't really understand why it works for badge and user but not for project..